# what does moment data from 2012-2020 mean?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to use moment.js to convert from one time zone to another in my js file. I was wondering what the below text mean ?

> For convenience, there are builds available on momentjs.com/timezone/
>   with all the zone data or a subset of the data with support for only
>   2012-2022.
>
> https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Does that mean `moment.js` supports conversion between timezones only if the date lies between 2012-2022 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use "2010-2020" file if your requirement lies in-between these years, it is lightweight and faster.**

Now come to your question:

> Does that mean moment.js supports conversion between timezones only if
>   the date lies between 2012- 2022 ?

Answer is **Yes** [2012- 2022](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js) file contain on data between 2012-2022. But it does not mean that [main file](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js) does not contain data of 2012-2022. That file also contains data but it is heavier than `moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js`

**Explanation**:

The reason for the two different files is that moment-timezone's data doesn't contain the year-over-year rules, but rather contains specific transitions for a given range of years.

To make faster lookup at runtime, but comes at the expense of having to decide on a subset of the data to work with.

The "all years" file contains all known transitions from the past, and then about 20 additional years of transitions into the future. The "2010-2020" file contains only the near past and near future.

Answer (score 1):

it means you can either use the full set or 2012-2022 subset depending on your needs

http://momentjs.com/timezone/

note that the 10yrs subset is only 9kb while the other one  is 25 kb

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version [0.5.41](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/changelog.md#0541-2023-02-25), you can use `moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range` instead of `moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022`.